# How to make outgoing localhost traffic use Windows proxy?

Tags: node.js, websocket, proxy

I am using this app https://github.com/nice-table/bitmex-scaled-orders to connect to testnet.bitmex.com through the api to place orders. I am running the app on Windows in node.js. It looks like the app starts a websocket on port 1337 and a bitmex proxy on port 8000. The app uses a GUI through the browser that you connect to through localhost:3006.

I have a proxy server set in Windows settings. I am unable to access localhost:3006 without the bypass proxy checkbox checked which makes sense. However, when I check the box, it seems as though outgoing traffic to bitmex is also bypassing my proxy. I am able to know because when I put wrong proxy info, the app still connects. Shouldn't this checkbox only apply to local traffic? Is there any way I can make this app use my proxy?

This can be used for testing, make sure the testnet is selected in the app

key ID: `9I0Ez-z-a8wAgM-IB03OMLg0`

key secret: `OzanemIvHP368THbeGjT6by5bABmYWIXQvAXILX6oumQpipY`

I am illiterate when it comes to this stuff please let me know if theres more info I can provide. I tried contacting the author on github but no answer.